# How can I put an Image in a title? Is it possible?

Tags: jquery, html

I really wanted to put an image in a title atribute, but it is possible?

And If so, how can I do it?

UPDATE

I wanted it to look just like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FINTW.jpg).

LAST UPDATE

It works now with Jquery UI.

Comment: So you want to show a img when hover over a link? Pleases be more precise!

Answer (score 2):

No, it's not possible using the HTML `title` attribute only.

If you want to add an image in a tooltip you would need to use a third party tooltip library which generates HTML tooltips, such as [Qtip2](http://qtip2.com/)

Comment: [boostrap](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tooltips) also has option, worth to add as it is widely used framework

Comment: That's true. I think jQueryUI has an implementation too.

Comment: Do you know any example of it?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, you are looking for a way to include **favicon** in your page, the image that lays on the left side of the page title in web browsers?

You can add favicon easily and I assume you'd be able to change it with jQuery as well (the source of the image at least).

Simply put this in between your `<head>` tags:

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="favicon.png"/>
```

The image itself should be around 16 - 64 pixels (square) and even more preferably converted to .ico format, though .png is supported nowdays too.

If this is not what you're looking for, the answer is simply **no, you can't include image in `<title>` tags**.

Comment: First off, Rory did not ask a thing in here, he holds one of the answers. Second, the question itself is very unclear. I am providing a simple answer for what could be what he/she is looking for.

Comment: @ProDexorite I updated it, look at the link and tell me how can I do like that please.

Comment: @BrunoMoutinho Do you mean the "info sign" next to the text or the image that pops out when you hover the text?